# Bash "command" equivalent in PowerShell

Tags: bash, powershell

Is there a "`command`" equivalent of Bash in PowerShell?

I used to over-ride certain command in Bash like this:

```
function npm(){
    command npm --no-color $@
}
```

I'd like to do the same in PowerShell, is there an equivalent of bash "command" in PowerShell?

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to run regular console applications such as dir.exe or something then you can use this.

```
function calc(){
    CMD /C "calc.exe" -arguments
}
```